# Происходит несколько отрисовок Activty подряд

Tags: android, activity

Существует некое простое приложение без сторонних библиотек, – практически идентичное тому, что использует *Android Studio* в качестве базового шаблона. Соответственно, все классы Activity наследуют именно `Activity`, а не `AppCompatActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Также используется примитивный стиль – с незначительными модификациями, – наследуемый от `@android:style/Theme.Material`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.AppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">...</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">...</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">...</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">...</item>
</style>
```

Непонятно, почему даже без вызова `setContentView(...)` отрисовывается экран приложения. Получается, комментирование `setContentView(...)` влияет – условно – только на наличие или отсутствие `Hello, World!` на экране. Можно, например, отключить `ActionBar` в стиле, но в целом ничего не изменится.
Насколько это поведение типично? Скажем, не хотелось бы, чтобы приложение тратило ресурсы на создание и стилизацию ненужных элементов, – потому что все впоследствии будет сделано в коде. А так, выходит, сперва приложение пытается отрисовать что-то там свое, а после выводит – визуально будто бы накладывает – один макет на другой.

В лучшем случае должно быть примерно так: запускается приложение, создается макет в коде и после выводится на экран. Причем, как указано выше, важно, – если это возможно, – чтобы приложение перед этим ничего не отображало.

Comment: `приложение тратило ресурсы на создание и стилизацию ненужных элементов` все ваши элементы находятся в лаяуте, который вы не подключили, а залить экран одним цветом, я думаю, не особо затратная операция... в общем, не стоит таким заморачиваться и экономить на спичках

Comment: Вероятно, вы правы. Насчёт ресурсов — точно, пожалуй. Но, помимо прочего, это доставляет эстетический дискомфорт. Например, другие приложения, которые довелось рассмотреть, лишены подобного изъяна. Могу прикрепить запись экрана, чтобы яснее выразить проблему.

Comment: Я понимаю, что Вы хотите « прозрачный слой вместо отрисованного экрана приложения. Это верно?